# Правильно организовать state у компонентов?

Tags: reactjs

Нахожусь в процессе изучения react.
Возник вопрос по поводу state. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как организовываются в плане архитектуры такие задачи:

Есть компоненты Контейнер -> Список -> Элемент. Элемент отражает объект с полями: ИД, Название и Описание.
Т.е. по большому счету на странице просто список объектов. Необходимо решить 3 разные задачи по сохранению изменений при редактировании этих объектов.

Задача 1. "Поэлементное сохранение". Т.е. при редактировании поля элемента (например, "Название") активируется кнопка "Сохранить", ну и "Отмена". На той же строке.
Задача 2. "Сохранение списка". При редактировании элемента активируется кнопка "Сохранить" и "Отмена" уже под списком и сохраняют все измененные элементы списка.
Задача 3. "Фоновое изменение". Без кнопок. Т.е. как только мы изменили значение поля, сразу идет сохранения.

Пожскажите, пожалуйста, какая должна быть архитектура в плане state и props  у компонентов?
Достаточно ли только state у контейнера, который содержит элементы items? Нужно ли вводить state для компонентов Список и Элемент?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в терминологии "контейнер-компонент" обычно подразумевается, что контейнер знает о состоянии приложения, тогда как компоненты не знают. таким образом, чем меньше это самое состояние размазано по разным файлам, тем проще разрабатывать и поддерживать приложение.

поэтому ваши компоненты (элементы списки) могли бы иметь в пропсах коллбэки типа onComplete, onSave, onEdit и т.д.

контейнер назначает действия на эти коллбэки:

```
 // in .map():
 <ListItem onSave={() => this.setState(prevState => (...))} />
```

насчёт "Контейнер -> Список -> Элемент":

из моей практики, наиболее простым вариантом, будет передать в список готовый массив элементов через children. список же дополнит эти элементы нужным обрамлением списка (хедер, футер или что там), а также может вывести их в таблице или как угодно. Конечно, всё зависит от задачи.

Comment: спасибо! 2 вопроса, пожалуйста, для новичка.  1) В вашем примере получается контейнер содержит ListItem, без списка, т.е. Контейнер -> Элемент? 2) "переделать в список готовый массив через children" можно чуть поподробнее, пожалуйста. Список это некий компонент?

Comment: насчёт 1) я думаю всё зависит от сложности компонентов, визуальных требования, и т.д. в простейшем случае можно обойтись двумя компонентам - контейнер + элемент списка, если там что-то более сложно, то можно и тремя и больше - лишь бы работало как следует
2) я там писал не "переделать" , а передать - имея в виду, что в компонент списка, если таковой имеется, мы можем передать элементы списка или в виде данные или в виде готовых нод реакта, так?x

Comment: в общем это всё теория, как сделаете - можете ссылку выложить (codesandbox к примеру), можно будет посмотреть..

в итоге лишь бы работало, за философию заказчики не платят почему-